# Get the result of a POST request through the WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, https, request

I have a WebBrowser control on a form, but for the most part it remains hidden from the user. It is there to handle a series of login and other tasks. I have to use this control because cloudflare forbid my request with webclient. the problem is that a download window appears and I would like to get the content in the background Or another solution would be to bypass cloudflare.

When I try to make a request with Webclient I get a 403 error and the error indicates that the server is protected by cloudflare (The server does not belong to me) and I found nothing to handle the result of my post request from my WebBrowser

currently I'm doing a post request from the webBrowser Like this :

```
    Dim URL = "https://xxxx/xxx/xxx/xx/xxx/xxxxy" 
    Dim postData As String = "login=jxx&password=pixxxxx9&long_life_token=false"
    Dim encoding As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    Dim bytes As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)
    Web.WebBrowser1.Navigate(URL, String.Empty, bytes, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

I would like to get the content of the webBrowser in a string without displaying a window to the user

[Example Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBRbU.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested declaring a Webbrowser control in the code (without adding it to the form), but it does not seem to do anything. This means you need to add it to the form, but it does not necessarily have to be visible.

```
WebBrowser1.Visible = False
WebBrowser1.Navigate(URL, "", bytes, "")
```

With an event handler linked to the `DocumentCompleted` event the result of the request can be displayed.

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    TextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.DocumentText
End Sub
```